# Fixed Column Widths in Resource FullCalendar

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I am using a special version of FullCalendar that supports Resource Views.
http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/

I only have a couple of problems with it. It seems to automatically set the column widths, which I think applying this sort of addresses that:

```
.fc-widget-header
{
    width:100px;
}
.fc-widget-content
{
    width:100px;
}
.fc-resourceName
{
    background-color:aliceblue;
    width:150px;
}
```

Then the html writes that width of the cells is 100px, but it is still trying to auto fit everything.

What I want it to do is if it is too big, to h-scroll, but I always want each cell to be exactly 100px.

I have this style for scrolling:

```
#calendar
{
    overflow-x:auto;
}
```

But the elements are still showing up as variable widths based on the date.
Here is what it looks like:

[image: enter code here]

Clearly, each of my columns are not 100px as I have requested, and the resource columns are not 150px as requested. What can I do to get the desired look?

The other problem is there is no class defined for a new week. I would really like to show the columns where week X is written as different colors.

Any insight into either of these would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For anyone searching for a solution in **Vertical Resource View**, this helped me:

```
.fc table{
    table-layout: auto;
}
.fc-view > table{  
    min-width: 0;
    width: auto;
}
.fc-axis{
    min-width:100px; /*the width of times column*/
    width:100px; /*the width of times column*/
}
.fc-day,.fc-resource-cell,.fc-content-col{
    min-width:300px;
    width:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I had that problem before, putting this line on my calendar table worked for me.

```
#calendar table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you so much.
I added it inside my media queries as I wanted this behaviour at all sizes e.g.
    @media (max-width: 767px) { #calendar table { table-layout: fixed; } }

Answer (score 1):

I know that my solution is not related, but thanks for "overflow-x:auto;" this helped me to solve my problem.

This works for me with original fullCalendar + Scheduler in agendaView using column resources in vertical view [like this](https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.6.2/demos/vertical-resource-view.html):

```
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
    div.fc-view.fc-agendaDay-view.fc-agenda-view table {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1170px) {
    div.fc-view-container {
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }
    div.fc-view.fc-agendaDay-view.fc-agenda-view table {
        min-width: 1170px;
    }
}
```

This way it was using the original min-width set to 120px for columns, is responsive but uses scrolling for extra size, so that it looks better on small devices.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes across this with a newer version of fullcalendar, you can use the slotWidth setting in v4, and slotMinWidth in v5/6.

If you want to override it per-view you can do it in the views property. In the following example all views will share the same slotMinWidth, except for resourceTimelineDay (a standard included view) which has an override.

```
slotMinWidth: 100,
views: {
   resourceTimelineDay: {
     slowMinWidth: 50
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 contentHeight: 'auto',
                aspectRation: 1.35,
})
```

This solve your issues

Answer (score 0):

They've solved this problem. You just need to install this plugin: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayMinWidth

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34362215)