# Fixed column size of FullCalendar

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I am trying to make the resource day view (https://github.com/jarnokurlin/fullcalendar) of FullCalendar with fixed column size.
I have tryed this for making the columns the same width:

```
.ui-widget-header
{
width:150px !important;
}
```

and this:

```
.fc th {
width:150px !important;
}
```

But the columns keep the size according to the size of the column content.

I have added horizontal and vertical scrollbars to the calendar could this be the problem?

I also tryed this: [Fixed Column Widths in Resource FullCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139527/fixed-column-widths-in-resource-fullcalendar) but that didn't work for me.

Thanks

Dani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem myself:
I had to add the table layout fixed directly to the table fc-border-separate not only table

```
table.fc-border-separate { table-layout: fixed; }
```

and then with:

```
table.fc-border-separate, table.fc-border-separate.fc td, .fc th {
width: 91px !important;
height: 50px !important;
}
```

the column size and height is fixed.

Adding    display: block didn't change anything but thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to those `selectors`.